# Upload File To Slack From Hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, slack-api

I am trying to upload a file that is being uploaded to my hapijs server directly to slack using the web api `files.upload`.
I get in return an error message `{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}`.
The same code works if i upload a file that already in the storage using `fs.createReadStream`

Here is my code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Path = require('path');
const Boom = require('boom');
const Utils = require('../utils');

const Request = require('request');

exports.routes = Promise.coroutine(function*(server, options) {

    server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: options.prefix,
        config: {
            tags: ['api', 'v1'],
            payload: {
                maxBytes: 2097152,
                output: 'stream',
                parse: true
            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    payloadType: 'form'
                }
            },
            validate: {
                payload: Joi.object({
                    cv: Joi.object({ pipe: Joi.func().required() }).required().unknown().description('CV file').meta({ swaggerType: 'file' })
                })
            },
            response: {
                emptyStatusCode: 204,
                schema: false
            },
            handler: Utils.coHandler(function*(request, reply) {
                const supportedFiles = ['docx', 'doc', 'pdf', 'pages'];
                const ext = Path.extname(request.payload.cv.hapi.filename).substr(1);

                if (!supportedFiles.filter((supExt) => supExt === ext).length) {
                    return reply(Boom.badRequest('Unsupported file type'));
                }

                Request.post({
                    url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
                    formData: {
                        token: 'XXXX',
                        filename: `${request.payload.name} - CV.${ext}`,
                        file: request.payload.cv,
                        channels: 'XXXX'
                    }
                }, (err, res, body) => {
                    console.log(body);
                });

                reply();
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I seem to be facing a similar problem.